# MD Paginator error: data.slice is not a function at MapSubscriber

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Nothing on the Web about this error :-(

It occurs with two actions in my MD Paginator in the MD Data Table.

1) When I click on the arrow for nextPage,

2) When I try to change the page size, say from 5 rows to 10.

The app crashes with this error.  Other than that, all is good with the Data Table display. It displays the 5 first items in the db and the item count at the bottom, in the pagination section, is 8, the total in the db.

Any idea what is happening and a fix?  I'm trying to put as much code as possible in the service because other components will use it.

First the html.  Notice that I add buttons in the rows of the last two columns and hide the contents of the row in the last column.  The buttons, and that hidden row, work fine.  I'm hoping they aren't the problem because I need them.  I commented them out in the html and the related displayedColumns in the component.ts and no help.

```
<md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

      <!-- First Name Column -->
      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="firstName">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}} </md-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Las Name Column -->
      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="lastName">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Last Name </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">  {{row.lastName}} </md-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Title Column -->
      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="mainSkillTitle">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Title </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.mainSkillTitle}} </md-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Main Skills Column -->
      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="mainSkills">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Main Skills </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row.mainSkills}} </md-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Delete Buttons Column -->
      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="delete">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Delete </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
          <button (click)="deleteMember(row.$key)">Delete</button> </md-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Edit button Column -->
      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="edit">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Edit </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
          <button (click)="goToDetailPage(row.$key)">Edit</button> </md-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Database key Column -->

      <ng-container cdkColumnDef="key">
        <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef class="hiddenField"> Key </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" class="hiddenField"> {{row.$key}} </md-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
      <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>


    </md-table>
    <md-paginator #paginator
                  [length]="dataLength?.length"
                  [pageIndex]="0"
                  [pageSize]="5"
                  [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
    </md-paginator>
```

The code in the service.ts with a console.log analysis.

```
// Data Table imports.
import { MdPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class MembersAdminService {

  private membersData$: FirebaseListObservable<MemberModel[]>;


  constructor(
    private af: AngularFireDatabase,
    private successService: SuccessService,

    @Inject(FirebaseApp) fb) {
      this.membersData$ = af.list('Members');
  }


  public getMembers(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    return this.af.list('Members', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'lastName'
      }
    });
  }

... CRUD functions
}  

export class MembersAdminSource extends DataSource<MemberModel> {

    constructor(
        private memberDatabase: MembersAdminService,
        private paginator: MdPaginator) {
        super();
    }

connect(): Observable<MemberModel[]> {
      const displayDataChanges = [
          this.memberDatabase.getMembers(),
          this.paginator.page
      ];
        // return Observable.of(this.memberDatabase); Old code that worked.

      return Observable.merge(...displayDataChanges).map((data, page) => {
          const dataSlice = data.slice();
          console.log('dataSlice', dataSlice); // console.log => Array of 3 objects, 8 total in db.

          // Get the page's slice per pageSize setting.
          const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
          const dataLength = this.paginator.length;
          console.log('dataLength', this.paginator.length); // console.log => 8 = correct.
          console.log('pageIndex', this.paginator.pageIndex); // console.log => 0 = correct.
          console.log('pageSize', this.paginator.pageSize); // console.log => 5 = correct.
          console.log('startIndex', startIndex);  // 0 = correct.
          return dataSlice.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
            // console.log => an array of 5 objects.  Seems to be correct. 3 more in db.
      });

    }

    disconnect() {}
}
```

The relevant code in the component.ts

```
export class AllMembersComponent implements OnInit {

  membersData: MemberModel[];
  private result: boolean;
  allMembers: MemberModel[];

  // For search
  startAt = new Subject();
  endAt = new Subject();
  lastKeypress: 0;

  // For MD data table.
  private dataSource: MembersAdminSource | null;
  private displayedColumns = [
      'firstName',
      'lastName',
      'mainSkillTitle',
      'mainSkills',
      'delete',
      'edit',
      'key'
  ];

  @ViewChild(MdPaginator)
  paginator: MdPaginator;

  public dataLength: any;
  private dataArray: any;

  constructor(
      private membersAdminService: MembersAdminService,
      private router: Router,
      private confirmService: ConfirmService,
      private memberDatabase: MembersAdminService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.membersAdminService.getMembers()
        .subscribe(members => {
            this.dataSource = new MembersAdminSource(this.memberDatabase, this.paginator);
            this.dataLength = members;
        });
}
... More stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took days of experimenting and study but I nailed the answer. This is how to setup MD Table with MD Paginator and import data from an external source such as Firebase.  I use a service for the source and database classes and most of the code goes into the service.  The reason I was getting the error is because I hadn't figured out how to wire in the first two lines of the MemberDatabase class.  That required creating the database class and refactoring the source class.  Neither Ben's or Andrew's solutions worked and I tried many permutations.  However, the first paragraph of Andrew's solution gave me the insight I needed to solve this myself. Big thanks Andrew!!

member-admin.service.ts

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MemberModel } from './member-admin.model';
import { SuccessService } from '../../../shared/success.service';

// Data Table imports.
import { MdPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class MembersAdminService {

  private membersData$: FirebaseListObservable<MemberModel[]>;

  constructor(
    public af: AngularFireDatabase,
    private successService: SuccessService,

    // For Create and Update functions.
    @Inject(FirebaseApp) fb) {
      this.membersData$ = af.list('Members');
    }

// ... CRUD stuff not relevant to the MD Table ...


// *** MD DATA TABLE SERVICES. ***


@Injectable()
export class MemberDatabase {

    /* Stream that emits whenever the data has been modified. */
    public dataChange: BehaviorSubject<MemberModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<MemberModel[]>([]);
    get data(): MemberModel[] {
        return this.dataChange.value; }

    // Connection to remote db.
    private database = this.memberAdminService.af.list('Members', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'lastName'
        }
    });
    public getMembers(): FirebaseListObservable<MemberModel[]> {
        return this.database;
    }


    constructor(private memberAdminService: MembersAdminService) {
        this.getMembers()
            .subscribe(data => this.dataChange.next(data));
    }
}


@Injectable()
export class MembersAdminSource extends DataSource<MemberModel> {


    constructor(
        private memberDatabase: MemberDatabase,
        private paginator: MdPaginator) {
        super();
    }


    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<MemberModel[]> {

      const displayDataChanges = [
          this.memberDatabase.dataChange,
          this.paginator.page,
      ];

      return Observable
          .merge(...displayDataChanges) // Convert object to array with spread syntax.
          .map(() => {
              const dataSlice = this.memberDatabase.data.slice(); // Data removed from viewed page.

              // Get the page's slice per pageSize setting.
              const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;

              const dataLength = this.paginator.length;  // This is for the counter on the DOM.

              return dataSlice.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
          });
    }
    disconnect() {}
}
```

all-members.component.ts 
Did some refactoring in ngOnInit and the class properties.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

// For MD Data Table.
import { MdPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { MembersAdminService, MembersAdminSource, MemberDatabase } from './member-admin.service';

import { ConfirmService } from '../../../shared/confirm.service';
import { MemberModel } from './member-admin.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-members',
  templateUrl: './all-members.component.html'
})


export class AllMembersComponent implements OnInit {

  membersData: MemberModel[];
  private result: boolean;
  allMembers: MemberModel[];

  // For search
  startAt = new Subject();
  endAt = new Subject();
  lastKeypress: 0;

    // For MD data table.

  // private memberDatabase = new MemberDatabase();  // Requires a param but? Moved to constructor.
  private dataSource: MembersAdminSource | null;
  private displayedColumns = [
      'firstName',
      'lastName',
      'mainSkillTitle',
      'mainSkills',
      'delete',
      'key'
  ];

  @ViewChild(MdPaginator)
  paginator: MdPaginator;

  public dataLength: any; // For member counter on DOM.

  constructor(
      private membersAdminService: MembersAdminService,
      private memberDatabase: MemberDatabase,
      private router: Router,
      private confirmService: ConfirmService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

      this.memberDatabase.getMembers()
          .subscribe(members => {
              this.dataSource = new MembersAdminSource(this.memberDatabase, this.paginator);
              this.dataLength = members;
          });
    }
```

There was no change in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Plainly put, it looks like `data` is not an Array (or an object with a `slice` method) where you're calling `data.slice()` inside of the method you're passing to `.map()`.

Offending line:

```ts
const dataSlice = data.slice();
```

One fix:

```
const dataSlice = Array.isArray(data) ? data.slice() : [];
```

It really depends on what you want to do if `data` isn't an Array.

Comment: Not sure I understand. This is the console.log:

dataSlice (8) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Each object has the data but I just noticed that there are only 3 objects in it instead of the 8 it says it has.  The page is for 5 rows so only the reminder are here, and the contents are the last three in the db.  I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: One of those times through `data` wasn't an array. Since the console is logging *after* your slice, you're missing it. Add a `console.log(data)` *before* the slice and see what you're getting beforehand.

Comment: This code is from the AM Paginator docs:  https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api.  I've modified it for using a service though.

Comment: Console.log(data): (8) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]  All objects have the correct data and are there.  Looks like an array to me but I'm a noob.

Comment: Ben, I replaced my code with yours but dataSlice is empty when I click the next page button. dataSlice [ ] length:0.

Comment: Ben, at least your solution doesn't crash the app :-)

Comment: Solved!  See my answer.  Big thanks Andrew for the insight to solve this myself!!

Answer (score 1):

`Observable.merge` is not returning both `data` and `page`. Instead, it returns the value of the last emitted value only. When the database sends an event, you store the result into `data` and correctly slice it. When the paginator sends an event, you store the page event into `data` and incorrectly slice it.

To resolve this, you have several options. One, you can use another merging function like `combineLatest` which will provide values as you have listed `(data, page)`. The issue will be that it will wait until all streams have emitted at least once, but the paginator does not emit until interacted with. You could add a start value by having `this.paginator.page.startsWith(null)` to start it off with an emitted value.

Second, you can have a separate subscription that stores your data,

```
  this.memberDatabase.getMembers().subscribe(data => this.data = data)
```

and then subsequently have your merge, but instead of capturing any values, just use `this.data` for the data and `this.paginator` for the current page values.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it will take some time for me to figure this out.  Studying Rx at the same time...  I copied and pasted the code from the AM2 Paginator doc and trying to understand it.  They put all the code in one component.ts which isn't how any of us are coding so I'm struggling to separate it as it should have been presented.  The console.log is showing page: 0 by the way.  I think that is correct for the first page but the 2nd page is crashing the app.

Comment: Andrew, what your are saying is beginning to make sense (to me).  After I click the next page button but before the app crashes I get the following in the console for data:  Object {pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 5, length: 8}   length:8 pageIndex:1 pageSize:5  The first call data contained all 8 objects in the db.  For page 2 it contains the above.  The console shows page 1 which is correct for an array, actually page 2, but it starts with page 0. I'm working through your options.

Comment: I've tried every permutation that I can think of for both solutions but nothing works. I feel that you are on the right track though.  I replaced .merge with combineLatest which failed to load the table with anything but couldn't find a place for the startsWith statement that worked.  Putting it in 'const displayDataChanges = [...'  created an amusing infinite loop :-)   For the 2nd solution I put the' this.data...' in the .map and tried several locations for the subscription but lots of errors.  I don't see removing code as part of solution.

Comment: In the AM2 docs this is in export ExampleDatabase.  I already have a Firebase db so I didn't include it in my code, but I think these two statements are important.  Maybe they belong in the service.   dataChange: BehaviorSubject<UserData[]> = new BehaviorSubject<UserData[]>([]);
        get data(): UserData[] { return this.dataChange.value; }